# Send data to server and wait an answer using http

Tags: angular, http, angular2-http

I want to send some data to the server and wait an answer from it in my `onSelected` method. Do you know how to do this with Angular using http? Here is my code:

```js
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import { CompleterService, CompleterData } from 'ng2-completer';
import { Logger } from '../../app/logger.service'
import { MapController } from './map.service'
import { BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';

export class TService {
    logger:Logger = new Logger(this.constructor.name);

    protected mapController:MapController;
    protected searchStr: string;
    protected dataService: any;
    private placeHolder = "select a field";

protected searchData = [
        { name: 'A',         desc: '1'},
        { name: 'B',         desc: '2'},
        { name: 'C',  desc: '3'}
      ];

constructor(private completerService: CompleterService, private Http:Http) {
        this.logger.log("TService()");
        this.dataService = completerService.local(this.searchData, 'name,desc', 'name')
        .descriptionField('desc')     
    }





        public onSelected(event:any) {
            this.logger.log(event);
            //I want to send to the server the object "Event" using a post after clicking on a button
            console.log(event);
         //http code
         
         //return ok if object received by the server           
            
        }
}
```

Comment: *Do you know how to do this with angular 2 using http ?* Yes, you do it as clearly described in any of hundreds of tutorials, intros, documentation pages, and blog posts, that can be easily Googled, or found on `angular.io` (such as [this tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you want to communicate via HTTP, you can use the `Http` class in angular.

Example:

```
this.http.post( 'URL', JSON.stringify( message)).map( ( res: Response ) => res.json() ).subscribe( ( response: Response ) => { /* do something with response */ } );
```

See this [link](https://github.com/kangaro0/lgs/blob/master/web/src/app/services/event.service.ts). It's a service I use for sending events to and from the server via JSON.

Edit: I think it's useful to create an additional service for making those HTTP-Requests, so you have a clear sectioning of your services. Maybe you can reuse it in another way :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 public onSelected(event:any) {
        this.logger.log(event);
        this.Http.post('your-post-url', JSON.stringify(event)) 
        .subscribe( response => {
           if(response.status === 200 ) {
             // Do something with the message, after success
           }
         })     
    }
```

the `subscribe` method will be only executed when the server response is received, then you can check if it's a success message (status code 200) and then do whatever you want, to notify user about the success.